# Stratified sampling WEKA

Tags: data-analysis, weka, sampling

How can I split a data set into a training and test set of sizes 70% and 30% of the original data set, respectively using stratified sampling in order to preserve the proportional class sizes in these new sets. I am trying to do this with WEKA.
The RemoveStratifiedFolds option I'm not sure how that divides the data. Using numfolds at 10 and setting folds to 7 and 3 would this work? Also, won't there be duplicate values?

New to WEKA and not really sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run the [StratifiedRemoveFolds](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/supervised/instance/StratifiedRemoveFolds.html) filter ten times with 10 generated folds separately (`-N` command-line option, `numFolds` property in GUI), as you need to extract each of the 10 folds separately (`-F` command-line option, `fold` property in GUI).

You can then combine seven of them into your 70% split and the remainder into your 30% split.

The [weka.core.Instances](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#main-java.lang.String:A-) class can be called from the command-line to append two ARFF files into a new one (output on stdout, redirect using `>` into a third file):

```bash
java -cp weka.jar weka.core.Instances append FILENAME1 FILENAME2 > FILENAME3
```

The individual folds will have no duplicates.

**Python**

If you are familiar with Python, you could use the [python-weka-wrapper3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3) library and script this tedious process:

```py
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
from weka.core.converters import load_any_file, save_any_file
from weka.core.dataset import Instances
from weka.filters import Filter

jvm.start()

# load data
data = load_any_file("some/where/data.arff", class_index="last")

# generate folds
folds = []
for i in range(10):
    remove_folds = Filter(classname="weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds",
                          options=["-N", "10", "-F", str(i+1)])
    remove_folds.inputformat(data)
    fold = remove_folds.filter(data)
    folds.append(fold)

# combine folds
train = Instances.template_instances(data)
for i in range(0, 7):
    train = Instances.append_instances(train, folds[i])

test = Instances.template_instances(data)
for i in range(7, 10):
    test = Instances.append_instances(test, folds[i])

# save splits
save_any_file(train, "/some/where/train.arff")
save_any_file(test, "/some/where/test.arff")

jvm.stop()
```

**Groovy**

A similar process could be achieved using Groovy as well (you need to install the **kfGroovy** Weka package). You can run the following script in Weka's **Groovy console** (from the *Tools* menu):

```
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSink
import weka.core.Instances
import weka.filters.Filter
import weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds

// load data
def Instances data = DataSource.read("/some/where/data.arff")
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1)

// generate folds
def folds = []
for (i in 1..10) {
  def removeFolds = new StratifiedRemoveFolds()
  removeFolds.setOptions(["-N", "10", "-F", "" + i] as String[])
  removeFolds.setInputFormat(data)
  fold = Filter.useFilter(data, removeFolds)
  folds.add(fold)
}

// combine folds
def train = null
for (i in 0..6) {
  if (train == null) {
    train = folds[i]
  }
  else {
    for (inst in folds[i])
      train.add(inst)
  }
}

def test = null
for (i in 7..9) {
  if (test == null) {
    test = folds[i]
  }
  else {
    for (inst in folds[i])
      test.add(inst)
  }
}

// save splits
DataSink.write("/some/where/train.arff", train)
DataSink.write("/some/where/test.arff", test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this today itself. For appending all the files throught hte WEKA GUI is there a way for should I manually just copy paste the data instances from the ARFF files into one?

Comment: Personally, I don't recommend copy/pasting to avoid potential errors. With code you can always reproduce your outputs, but not so much with a GUI. However, if you want to go with copy/pasting then you can combine the data (below the `@data`) from the ten ARFF files that you generated into your train/test split files (all files will have the same header section).